# IE8 not loading jQuery 2.0 even though it's the first include and it's loaded from the same domain?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have a page in which I use jQuery for damn nearly everything, thus I find it kind of problematic when jQuery won't load in IE8 (works fine in IE9 and, I presume, IE10).

I've tried all the usual trickery: putting jQuery at the top of the header and I am loading the file from the same site as I am trying to run. I always do these things, but now you know ;)

The IE8 console isn't to much help, as it just bangs on about stuff being undefined, and not having this and that property and method. All i can get out of it is that the jQuery file is being loaded (it finds errors in that too :/), but for same reason it isn't working.

If someone would be so kind as to have a look at it, [this is a link to the actual page](http://cheerfultree.com/randomstuff/Cheerfulroster.htm).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery 2.0 completely dropped support for IE 8. You need to use 1.10.2 to support IE 6,7,8

They both currently have all the same features and functionality but 2.0 and up is smaller in KB due to dropping legacy code for IE and earlier.

60% of my visitors are on IE8 so I will be using v1.x for a long time

Comment: +1 for giving basically the same answer as me as pretty much the same time.

Comment: Thanks! :). I completely missed that :/. I don't know how many of my visitors will be on which browser, however, I think it is worth the extra few bytes to support an extra 10-12% of the worlds end users.

Comment: No problem, I like the look of your site by the way, it feels quite modern. Good Luck!

Answer (score 4):

It's not surprising that this doesn't work, because **jQuery v2 does not support IE8**.

It says so very clearly [on the jQuery site](http://jquery.com/download/).

You need to use jQuery v1.x if you want to support IE8 or earlier.

(the functionality of v1.10 is identical to v2; the only difference is that v2 removes all the extra code they had in there to support old IE versions)